# Django GenericForeignKey Referential INtegrity

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, referential-integrity, generic-foreign-key

I'm new to django programming, and trying to get to grips with GenericForeignKeys.

I've managed to create a generic foreign key which stores in the database, but the model does not appear to enforce referential integrity,

(i.e. I can create a reference to an ID of an object type where that object id does not exist)

(eg: content_type: "post", content_id: 123, but post 123 does not exists).

(Before you say it - Yes - I'm aware that Django has some facility for tagging - this is a really simple example/test for me to understand Generic Foreign Keys, and figure out how they work, so I can implement them in other situations)

My basic model is:

```
    class Tag(NamedModel, models.Model):
        taggable_models = models.Q(models.Q(model='post') | models.Q(model='discussion'))
        content_type = models.ForeignKey(
            ContentType,
            models.CASCADE,
            limit_choices_to=taggable_models,
        )

        content_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(
            _("content id"),
        )

        content_object = GenericForeignKey(
            'content_type',
            'content_id',
        )
```

In my admin.py, I have:

```
    @admin.register(Tag)
    class TagAdmin(VersionAdmin):
        readonly_fields = ('created_at',)
        list_display = ('content_type', 'content_id', 'created_at', )
        fieldsets = (
            (None, {
                'fields': ('content_type', 'content_id', 'created_at', ),
            }),
        )
        autocomplete_lookup_fields = {
            'generic': [['content_type', 'content_id']],
        }
```

However, when I run the admin page, it will allow me to create a Tag against a post id that does not exist.

Is there some way that I can enforce referential integrity here?  I guess I need to use the content_object GenericForeignKey somehow, but I can't figure out how to do this?

Thank kindly for any help,

Christopher.